# Primefaces facet footer style

Tags: primefaces, footer, background-color

How can I change the footer style of Primefaces (3.5) datatable footer? Or more specifically, its background-color?

I tried skinning it with .ui-datatable-footer but it doesn't seem to work. However, doing the same with color works perfectly, font-weight too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to use `important` alongside your background prop

```
.ui-datatable-footer {
   background: red !important;
 }
```

Comment: Even if it works, avoid the use of !important. Try to understand the css layers in your project

Comment: Is there a way to put a custom style on an f:facet footer?